# Median of new data using previous data statistics

Tags: math, statistics, data-science

How can i find combined median if I have percentile of of previous data but not all elements and a new list of data?

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question so that it's clearer. It would help to add an example and also your work so far.

Comment: Any old elelment might become a median, so you need to store all data